# Access query called as stored procedure via ADO can't retrieve from linked tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to use VBA from Excel 2007 to execute a query in an Access 2007 DB as a stored procedure.  The query retrieves data from a few MS SQL tables linked via an ODBC DSN.  The authentication for the external tables is done with `Windows NT authentication with Trusted_Connection=Yes`

I have tried connecting to the linked tables with both a User and System DSN - either way works fine when I run the query from Access 2007.

When I try using VBA in Excel the data that should be coming from the Windows authenticated tables isn't retrieved.  I am able to retrieve data from a set of linked MS SQL tables that are using a stored UID.

Here is the connection string I'm using:

```
strDB = xlWb.Path & "\database\dbQueries.accdb"
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strDB & ";"
```

And here is the command that's only partially successful (with data from the UID authenticated tables):

```
With cmd2
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "qryAppendtblOutput"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append cmd2.CreateParameter("[Start Date]", adDBDate, adParamInput, , startDate)
End With

cmd2.Execute
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: With a query name of 'qryAppendtblOutput' is this supposed to return rows? I just ran your code to append data to a table in Access and it worked?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I am able to retrieve data from a set of linked MS SQL tables that are using a stored UID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue by switching to the Access ODBC driver instead of the OLE DB provider.  I changed my connection string to:

```
strDB = xlWb.Path & "\database\dbQueries.accdb"
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
   "Dbq=" & strDB & ";" & _
   "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

Then, all I had to do was adjust the syntax of the underlying queries in Access to meet the requirements of this driver (I had to replace all double quotes with singles).

Thanks very much to all who reviewed my question :)!